# Django ForeignKey Big lsit when try to adding

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am coding in python, I have below problem:

I have models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    BadgeBarcode = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ManagerName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    UserLogin = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ShiftPattern = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def Add(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.EmployeeName


class Permission(models.Model):
    Permission_Name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Priority = models.IntegerField(unique=True)


    def Add(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Permission_Name

class EmployeePermission(models.Model):

    Employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    Permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission)
    Have = models.BooleanField()

    def Add(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Employee
```

I want to connect Model Employee and Permission and its all working fine.But I have like 7k records of employees and when I want to add new permission for employee, list of employees is too big and page is working likes... its any way to fix that or change list for search button or something?

## Edit

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ( 'id','EmployeeName','UserLogin',         
    'ManagerName','ShiftPattern','BadgeBarcode')
    list_filter =  ( 'ManagerName','ShiftPattern')


class EmployeeResources(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee


class ExportEmployeeAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = EmployeeResources
    list_filter =  ( 'ManagerName','ShiftPattern')
    list_display = ('id','EmployeeName','UserLogin','here many field...' )

admin.site.register(Employee,ExportEmployeeAdmin)



class PermissionResources(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Permission

class ExportPermissionAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PermissionResources
    list_display = ('Permission_Name', 'Priority')
    list_filter = ('Permission_Name', 'Priority')


admin.site.register(Permission,ExportPermissionAdmin)




class EmployeePermissionResources(resources.ModelResource):

class Meta:
    model = EmployeePermission


class ExportEmployeePermissionAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = EmployeePermissionResources
    list_display = ('Employee','Permission', 'Have')
    list_filter = ('Employee','Permission', 'Have')


admin.site.register(EmployeePermission,ExportEmployeePermissionAdmin)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? If the request is slow, show us the code that fetch the data as well.

Comment: and where do you want it? in the admin or your created view?

Comment: the list of employees in adding page (admin) is to big, i want to change list to something else

Comment: Not getting your problem, please be expressive while posting question @ŁukaszHerka

Comment: Gusy, when i am going to add new permission for employee in admin page i have 3 fields:

Employee
Permission
Have

The employee field is drop down list with 7k rows and it is hard to use and even list is loading for while

so i want to change the drop down list of employees for something else